# REG ADD syntax issue

Tags: batch-file, registry

I'm trying to make a batch file that creates a entry in the **registry**.
The entry must be link to a executable. It needs two parameters :

1. (path) The folder to process (see below *project1*)
2. (path) The folder that will contain the file returned by the process. I want this to be the parent folder of the first parameter (see below *DirectoryProject*)

Tree :

```
../somewhere/my/program/program.exe
../DirectoryProject
../DirectoryProject/project1
../DirectoryProject/output.data
```

Exemple :

```
"../somewhere/my/program/program.exe" "../DirectoryProject/project1" "../DirectoryProject"
```

The first parameter is easy, it is %%1. It has the folder's path I right clicked as value. The last parameter is however harder to get.
I first tried to manipulate the variable %%1.

```
reg add "%RootKey%\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\%KeyName%\command" /VE /D "cmd /c cd \"%%1\" & \"%Exec%\" \"%%1\" \"%%~dp1\"" /F
```

The program logs the parameters it reveice. The last parameter is equal to %%~dp1 so it does not work.

Then I tried a tricky way using the first parameter and the CD command

```
reg add "%RootKey%\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\%KeyName%\command" /VE /D "cmd /c cd \"%%1\" & \"%Exec%\" \"%%1\" \"%CD%\"" /F
```

In this case %CD% will always be the path of the batch file so clearly not what I want nether

I'm still looking

Thanks for your interest and help

Comment: What are you trying to do? I'm on *W10* and `/K` is not among *reg.exe add*'s options. Are you trying to set *command* value under parent key? Is this some kind of a (lame attempt of a) dirty hack?

Comment: So far, -1. I'll retract it after (**if**) improving the question.

Comment: Yeah I corrected the options, some of them didn't even existed

Comment: From my reading of `2.` you cannot pass a parameter as input to an executable which is the output from the executable. Is there any reason why you cannot provide us with the name and process of the executable and explain why you think a right click context menu could be a working option. When you run the executable from a command prompt or batch file, what would you use?

Comment: U got it wrong, maybe I was not clear about the last parameter.
I updated my question.

If you are curious about the executable take a look at https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/Addon_Builder
It is a tool that build folder into a extension for ArmA3 game.

I would like to use the contextual menu to make it faster to use in everyday tasks

Answer (score 0):

If the value of `%1` is a fully qualified and existing path then the root folder would generally be the drive letter followed by a backslash, normally denoted by `%~d1\`. However, given your latest clarification, it appears your looking for the current working directory, commonly denoted as `%CD%`.

I'm assuming that you wanted to manipulate the second instance of `%1`, so based on my assessment, here's how I'd do it:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "ExePath=C:\SomePathTo\MadeUp.exe"
Set "MenuTxt=Process with MadeUp"
Set "KeyName=LaunchTest"
Set "RootKey=HKCU"
Reg Add "%RootKey%\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\%KeyName%" /VE /D "%MenuTxt%" /F >Nul
Reg Add "%RootKey%\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\%KeyName%\command" /VE /D "\"%ExePath%\" \"%%~1\" \"%CD%\"" /F >Nul
```

- Please make sure that you modify your specific executable path on line `2` as required.
- Note that the text description you want in the context menu, currently `Process with MadeUp` can be changed to suit your preference, you can do that on line `3`.
- I have left your registry key name as you had it, `LaunchTest`, this can be changed in line `4`, *(when it's no longer a test).*
- A user menu entry should be entered into the `HKCU` key, so I'm using that.
  *(If you want it for all users then change `HKCU` to `HKLM` on line `5`. Whilst it does not match your provided key, it is the correct way to do it. Entries from both `HKCU\Software\Classes` and `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes` are auto propagated to `HKCR`, you shouldn't add things directly to it.
  If you change it to `HKLM` be aware that there's a likelihood the script will need to be run As administrator)*
- If you had wanted the root directory of the right clicked folder then you'd change `\"%CD%\"` to `\"%%~d1\\\"` on line `7`.

Comment: Given your clarification above, I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I was wrong finaly lol I tried to execute a program on a folder in the same directy as my batch so it made me think it works but I could be everythere it always links to the batch path

Comment: You really need to update your question once you've clarified what path you want the second parameter to be. When that's done, I'll try to see if I can update my answer again.

Comment: Yeah It was not clear in the beginning so after all the edit we can't see anything. I cleaned it all